# Creating a repository for each dropdown

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

**Order** is aggregate root and City is managed by OrderRepository as below -

```
Order -> ManyToOne -> City
City -> No relation -> Order
List<Order> findByCity(City city) // OrderRepository
```

For cities table, I therefore did not create **CityRepository**.

I was avoiding creating a repository for City since Order was containing it in findByCity.

```
Problem : I have to now show a dropdown in client will all cities.
```

Creating a repository for City will provide findAll() on City and get all cities but then Order no longer remains Aggregate as we have 2 repositories.

Is there better approach for it using SDR since in this way for every dropdown in UI I have to create a repository to expose it as paged resource.

One I can think of :

```
@Query("select c from City c") 
List<City> findAllCity();  //OrderRepository instead of CityRepository
```

Comment: What you want to have order reference in the cities, I think use another repository is a good idea, not sure what you mean with order no longer remains aggregate, this will happens as you dont have a relationship, but I think that is ok

Comment: Koitoer, I was just thinking if I could get away with creating CityRepository for these dropdowns. There is relationship between Order and City and I have kept that in Order side only. Creating a repository also exposes them as REST endpoint and that is where I meant Order was root repository. But I think having separate CityRepository while having single directional relationship as above should be ok..

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried doing a distinct in the city field, doing this in your OrderRepository

```
Query("select distinct(o.cities.name) from Orders o") 
List<String> findAllCity();
```